# Simulating results from logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, dataset, simulation

After predicting the probability of success for each datapoint in a logistic regression model i would like to run a simulation to simulate the number of succeeded iterations.

Im not trying to do something super advanced so my first thought was to maybe iterade through each predicted probability and simulate a value between 0 and 1 from a uniform distribution and then compare the simulated value with the predicted probability. If the simulated value S is lesser than the probability P then this will be coundet as a success, else it fails.

I'm just wondering what types of arbitrary simulations you guys can come up with and mainly if you think that my simulation is good, bad , worthless etc

Comment: I don't know the context of what you are trying to do, but an interesting thing to try could be to simulate the data points themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically trying to sample $n$ independent Bernoulli trials with success probabilities given by your predictions.

Your approach is fine and can be done in one line in R.

`num.successes <- sum(runif(n) < predictions)`.

Or you can just use the binomial random number generator

`num.successes <- sum(rbinom(n,1,predictions))`.

Comment: sweet, thanks for the answer and +1 for writing lines of code aswell :)